# Python Selenium. Why does the button press send the bot to the home page instead of the intended checkout page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a buying bot with python selenium. on this [website](https://www.inet.se/produkt/5410779/lian-li-grafikkortshallare), when you press **Köp** *(Buy in swedish)* you can see that the product list is loading the product you just put in the cart. The Bot is pressing the buy button, then it is supposed to press the **Till Kassan** *(To checkout)* button and then register information. The problem I'm having is that the bot presses the checkout button quicker than the product itself loads in the cart, so instead of going to checkout, it sends the bot to the home page.

There is no error being shown (besids the bluetooth default adapter failed, which I don't think affects anything), and I have tried to add an `wd.implicitly_wait(10)` before the button click, which does nothing.

Here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_binary

# Open the browser and the website
options = wd.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
wd = wd.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get("https://www.inet.se/produkt/5410779/lian-li-grafikkortshallare")
wd.implicitly_wait(10)

# Click the BUY button
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/button').click()

# Click the GO TO CHECKOUT button when it loads in a popup
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div[2]/nav/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a'))).click()
```

It does seem working fine when you press the checkout button with your mouse, but I assume that the bot does it too quickly and breaks it. There must be a way to make a timer somehow or wait untill the product loads, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

As I was writing this question I found this answer, and I thought why I don't answer it.
On [this website about how to wait on elements in selenium python](http://allselenium.info/wait-for-elements-python-selenium-webdriver/#:%7E:text=An%20implicit%20wait%20instructs%20Selenium,before%20any%20operations%20on%20element.) there are a lot of different types of waits. In this specific case you need to use the explicit wait, meaning that the bot will wait for the product list to load first and **then** press the checkout button.

Here is the code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_binary

# Open the browser and the website
options = wd.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
wd = wd.Chrome(options=options)
wd.get("https://www.inet.se/produkt/5410779/lian-li-grafikkortshallare")
wd.implicitly_wait(10)

wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/button').click()

# This will wait untill an element inside the products element in the ul list loads, ensuring that the item has loaded completely.
WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div[2]/nav/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/ul/li/div/article/div[4]/button')))
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/div[2]/nav/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a').click()
```

Another important thing to note, is that you can't wait in this case for the li element to load, because in some cases the li element of the product loads before the rest of  the information, still sending the bot to the home page. I fixed that by using the XPath of an element inside of that particular li element.